# Change link attribute when scrolling to anchor

Tags: javascript, scroll, anchor

Can someone please put me out of my misery and 'fix' or 'solve' my issue: as you can see via my JSfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/SJkmh/312/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var h = $("#main-menu").height() * 1.25;
    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - h
        }, 300);
    });
```

I can't seem to get it to work - all I want to do is change the colour of the link text to identify what section of the page the user is on.  please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your conditions for link2 and 3 never runs. Link1 conditions is the only one that becomes true

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** : Select menu item on scroll

[*UPDATED*] jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/Qtjx6/2/

**added js**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        // Get container scroll position
        var topHeight = $(this).scrollTop() + h + 10;
        var onTopId;
        $(".testx").each(function () {
            var curTop = $(this).offset().top;
            var curBottom = curTop + $(this).height();

            if (curTop < fromTop && curBottom > topHeight) {
                onTopId = $(this).attr("id");
            }
        });
        $selLink.removeClass("selected");
        $selLink = $("a[href=#"+onTopId+"]").addClass("selected");
    });
```

This should do the task : http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/Qtjx6/

**js**

```
var $selLink = $("ul li a"); 
$(function(){
    $("ul li a").click(function(){
        $selLink.removeClass("selected");
        $selLink = $(this);
        $selLink.addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

**css**

```
.selected{
    color : #4B85C3;
}
```

Comment: `$(this).addClass("selected")` will suffice, there is no point assigning it since you are only using it once.

Comment: this is great and so much more simple than I had originally, however can I add the same effect if the sections i.e. anchors are scrolled to instead of clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the offset of the links not the content sections. Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SJkmh/315/

```
$(document).scroll(function () {

    var h = $("#main-menu").height() * 1.5;
    var link1 = $("#home").offset().top;
    var link2 = $("#about").offset().top;
    var link3 = $("#work").offset().top;
    var selectedColor = "#4B85C3";
    var defaultColor = "#2e375b";
    var top = $(this).scrollTop() - h;
    $("#main-menu li a").css('color', defaultColor);    

    if (top <= link1) {
        $("#link1").css('color', selectedColor);
    } else if (top <= link2) {
        $("#link2").css('color', selectedColor);
    } else {
        $("#link3").css('color', selectedColor);
    }

});
```

Comment: this is the one, exactly what I wanted thank you Jonathan. there is one more thing I need it to do though: how do I get 'About Me' to revert back to default colour when going back to #home?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be to reset the color of all the links, and then set the color of the $(this) to the new color

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var h = $("#main-menu").height() * 1.25;
    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        $('a.scroll').css({"color": "#2e375b"});
        $(this).css({"color": "#4B85C3"});
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - h
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJkmh/314/)